# Use Azure Pipelines Conditions to change Task Command passed to GradleTask

Tags: android, gradle, azure-pipelines

I have an Android app setup on VSTS that is running a series of Gradle Tasks.

```
  steps:
          - script: echo Building!

          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Gradle Clean
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: ${{ variables.GRADLE_WRAPPER_FILE }}
              gradleOptions: ${{ variables.GRADLE_OPTIONS }}
              publishJUnitResults: false
              tasks: 'clean'

          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Gradle Assemble Release
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: ${{ variables.GRADLE_WRAPPER_FILE }}
              gradleOptions: ${{ variables.GRADLE_OPTIONS }}
              publishJUnitResults: false
              tasks: 'assembleRelease'

          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Gradle Lint
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: ${{ variables.GRADLE_WRAPPER_FILE }}
              gradleOptions: ${{ variables.GRADLE_OPTIONS }}
              publishJUnitResults: false
              tasks: 'lint'

          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Gradle Test
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: ${{ variables.GRADLE_WRAPPER_FILE }}
              gradleOptions: ${{ variables.GRADLE_OPTIONS }}
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
              tasks: 'test'
```

My application structure has several Product Flavours / Build Variants, and the `assembleRelease` command takes a *llloooonnggg* time - so much that the Task is often timing out as it goes over the 60 minute limit!

Now, I have various of my Flavours/Variants that exist on certain Long-Term-Support branches, so I am thinking about trying to use the `condition` - using `startsWith System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` to determine what branch the Pull Request is aimed at, and passing a smaller subset of `assembleXYZ` commands in the `tasks: ...` block.

From what I can tell, `conditions` normally makes a *task/step/job/stage* run or skip... so am not sure if my line of thinking is going to work.

Is this kind of thing even possible? 
Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but you can add another `Gradle@2` task with the condition and the smaller commands and in the regular task do reverse condition

Comment: Hmmm. May be the way to go.